# Is it good practice to stack multiple user controls on top of each other?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

In my C# class, we use Visual Studio.  My teacher says it is really not good practice to be stacking controls or panels on top of each other and hiding and showing them when needed. They say it should all be kept to separate forms.  However, this puzzles me.  I can understand that if you are in design mode, it is a little strange to see all these controls on top of each other, but you edit them all separately, so I don't see the issue.  I think its really odd to be closing and opening forms like that and it looks a bit strange to the user.

Say you had an application in which you wanted to use multiple controls on top of each other.  Say for example it was a login/register form and you didn't want to use a tab control, for whatever reason, and you wanted buttons in the menu strip to switch between the login or register user control, wouldn't it make sense to simply hide/show user controls?

Comment: If I am understanding right, there is a third option that is available which is to just add/remove child controls from the parent's controls collection at run time. This avoids both design view clutter issue as well as the "window hell scenario". I would tend to find this to be the most maintainable route when I find myself in this scenario.

Comment: multiple forms is a design decision and a rather outdated one, imo. Multiple UCs or other groups of controls can be parked in a hidden TabControl so you can access them easier in the designer. When you want to show then simply change the parent to some placeholder and when done back to theit tabpage.. - But a lot depends one the details: If one is used only once for loggin in I would indeed put it into a form of its own and even show it modally.

Comment: Were can I see this hierarchy of parent and child?